# PySpark - Access struct field name and value when exploding

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My input data is of this form:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "embedded": {
      "a": {
        "x": true,
        "y": 1,
      },
      "b": {
        "x": false,
        "y": 2,
      },
    }, 
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "embedded": {
      "a": {
        "x": false,
        "y": 3,
      },
      "b": {
        "x": true,
        "y": 4,
      },
    }, 
  },
]
```

Due to some complexities of my pyspark setup, the `embedded` field is a **struct** with fields `a` and `b` on it.  Though there may be more than `a` and `b` keys in the future, and I don't want to hard code the field list into the script.

I'd like to have the final data be of the form:

```
_______________________________
| id   |  key   |   x   |   y  |
_______________________________
| 123  |  a     |  true |   1  |
_______________________________
| 123  |  b     | false |   2  |
_______________________________
| 456  |  a     | false |   3  |
_______________________________
| 456  |  b     |  true |   4  |
_______________________________
```

I get that I want to explode the `embedded` field to get at the different values of it, but how can I access the field names?

Using the PySpark below, I'm able to extract all the value for the `id`, `x`, and `y` columns, but how can I access the struct field names (`a`, `b`, ...) when exploding?

```
frame = frame.select(
        explode(array("embedded.*")).alias("embedded"),
        frame.id,
    )
    frame = frame.select(
        frame.id,
        frame.embedded.x,
        frame.embedded.y,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, you should use [`MapType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/types/MapType.html) instead

```
df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    Row(id=123, embedded={'a': Row(x=True, y=1), 'b': Row(x=False, y=2)}),
    Row(id=456, embedded={'a': Row(x=False, y=3), 'b': Row(x=True, y=4)})
])
df.select(col("id"), explode(col("embedded"))).select(col("id"), col("key"), col("value.*")).show()
```

Output:

```
.+---+---+-----+---+
| id|key|    x|  y|
+---+---+-----+---+
|123|  a| true|  1|
|123|  b|false|  2|
|456|  a|false|  3|
|456|  b| true|  4|
+---+---+-----+---+
```

`StructType`s are tied to schemas which are meant to be static. If you really want to do this for `StructType`s, the queries need to be generated programmatically

```
df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    Row(id=123, embedded=Row(a=Row(x=True, y=1), b=Row(x=False, y=2))),
    Row(id=456, embedded=Row(a=Row(x=False, y=3), b=Row(x=True, y=4)))
])

field_names = [field.name for field in next(field for field in df.schema.fields if field.name=="embedded").dataType.fields]

dfs = [df.select(col("id"), lit(field_name).alias("key"), col(f"embedded.{field_name}.x"), col(f"embedded.{field_name}.y")) for field_name in field_names]

reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y), dfs).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+-----+---+
| id|key|    x|  y|
+---+---+-----+---+
|123|  a| true|  1|
|456|  a|false|  3|
|123|  b|false|  2|
|456|  b| true|  4|
+---+---+-----+---+
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I'm using AWS Glue, which is in control of the structure of the data frame, otherwise I'd definitely use a map!